# Some exercises about functions

Tags: functions

I need some exercises about functions in general to make sure that I understand it, in a book or a material book. Concepts like function in general (the definition of function), concepts like one-to-one, onto and closure.

Comment: I don't think this qualifies neither as a question nor as something we do here. Why not to use google?

Comment: @DonAntonio: We have had this kind of question before, be sure that I know enough about Google and the fact that I can use it.

Comment: @WillHunting: I think everybody knows that. If you could name some of them, it'd be more helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the section on functions in the first chapter of *Fundamentals of Abstract Algebra* by Malik, Mordeson and Sen for numerous exercises.